# How can I import parameters to behat.yml config file?

Tags: yaml, behat

I have large behat.yml file that has a lot of repeating code (for example multiple suites are shared by multiple profiles). I wish to import some `.yaml` files that hold these suites.

I have tried to include some parameters from another `.yaml` like this

```
imports:
  - parameters.yaml

...

suite:
  paths:
    features: "%%variable.name%%"
```

but it doesn't seem to work in any case. Using this to import the parameters also doesn't work.

```
imports:
  - { resource: parameters.yaml }
```

How I'd like it too look like

```
imports:
  - parameters.yaml
  - suites.yaml
  - something_else.yaml

profile_name:
  autoload:
    # import from parameters.yaml here
  suite_name:
    # import suites from suites.yaml here
  extensions:
    ...
```

Is this possible to do in Behat 3?